# update the row in MySQL, without ORM

Tags: python, mysql, flask

Why I got the value of uid

in flask debug console and while using

```
<input id="userId" name="userId" type="text" value= {{ un[usernumber][0] }} >
```

but get the error when use with mysql.connection.cursor() ?

Please help me to figure out why this happen and fix it.

https://ideone.com/TtKdJx

```
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute(
            "UPDATE User SET email='" +
            form.email.data +
            "', phone='" +
            form.phone.data +
            "', mphone='" +
            form.mphone.data +
            "', status='" +
            form.status.data + 
            #"' WHERE userId='12' ") # ok

            "' WHERE userId='" + uid + "' ")  
            # TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, 
            # not 'NoneType' 
            # and IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

        rv = cur.fetchall()
        mysql.connection.commit()
        return 'ok'
```

Debug console:

# right, we got the needed value

```
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger pin code: ...-...-...
uid: 2
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Jun/2016 17:20:28] "GET /edit?i=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Answer (score 0):

You **must not** do this. See [Little Jonny Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) as to why.

Please use the facilities of the DB API that are intended to stop attacks like this. Apart from the security benefit, your code will be simpler and easier to understand as a result.

```
cur.execute(
    "UPDATE User SET email=%s, phone=%s, mphone=%s, status=%s WHERE userId=%s",
    (form.email.data, form.phone.data, form.mphone.data, form.status.data, uid)
)
```